# Unable to locate package linux-image-4.8.0-53-generic

Tags: boot, debian, apt

I am trying to prepare a Debian 8.9 boot disk following [these](http://verahill.blogspot.co.at/2013/03/361-installing-debian-on-usb-stick-from.html) instructions. Obtaining a kernel image via `apt` is part of this process. However, if I try

```
apt install linux-image-`uname -r`
```

I run into the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.8.0-53-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.8.0-53-generic'
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is as follows:

```
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

What is the appropriate way for obtaining `/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-53-generic` (or an equivalent) with a Debian package?

Comment: That can easily happen when the package got updated (say, due to a security release) and you're running an outdated one—hence the version `uname -r` has no more bearing on the version of the actual available package. For this reason, Debian provides a set of virtual `linux-image*` packages. The best bet typically is to `apt install linux-image-amd64`—that is, `linux-image-$arch`: it will automatically pull what's needed.

Comment: As an aside, when you're wondering "which package contains a particular file?", your best friend is the https://packages.debian.org which allows searching packages *by their contents.*

Comment: BTW I fail to grasp why you need to copy the kernel image in the first place. The point (2) in the guide you mention—running `debootstrap`—should have had you covered in all aspects except installing the bootloader.

Comment: @kostix Thx. If you want to write up your comments as an anser, I shall accept it. Re copy, it was my impression that `$TARGET/boot` was empty after `debootstrap`, but maybe something else went wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not install the [`linux-image-4.8.0-53-generic`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/linux-image-4.8.0-53-generic) using the `sources.list` :

```
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

because the package belong to Ubuntu.

The only available `linux-image` for debian Jessie on the `main` component is [inux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64)

You should edit your `sources.list` as follow:

```
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free 
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
```

then:

```
apt update 
apt install linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I have circumnavigated the problem by copying the "host"'s kernel image into the "guest"'s filesystem. This amount to executing this copy before `chroot $TARGET`:

```
cp /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-53-generic $TARGET/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-53-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you may need to do

```
sudo apt-get update # This will update the repositories list
sudo apt-get upgrade # This will update all the necessary packages on your system
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # This will add/remove any needed packages
reboot # You may need this since sometimes after a upgrade/dist-upgrade, there are some left over entries that get fixed after a reboot
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r) # This should work now
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sadly it didn't work for me `E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.5.7-std-3`